# IFERROR INDEX/MATCH formula having application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, formula, autofill

I am trying to create a macro allowing me to autofill data from another workbook using INDEX MATCH. I have used the exact code for another formula and it works but when i simply replace for formula in the code below, it gives me a "application-defined or object-defined error"

Below is my code. The formula in question starts after `.formula`. The rest of the code exists for me to autofill empty cells and it has already worked with another macro.

```
Sub FillOrderType()   
Dim LR As Long
LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,
SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
With Range("H2:H" & LR)
With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]EXP'!N:N, MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]EXP'!L:L,0)), IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]AOG'!N:N,MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]AOG'!L:L,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]SCHED'!M:M,MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]SCHED'!K:K,0)),"")))"
End With
.Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Any help identifying the problem would be greatly appreciated. And I apologise for the long formula, I have tried to wrap it by using `_` but it just didn't work.

EDIT:

I believe that the issue lies solely on the formula itself since it highlights whenever I try debugging

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]EXP'!N:N, MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]EXP'!L:L,0)), IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]AOG'!N:N,MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]AOG'!L:L,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]SCHED'!M:M,MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]SCHED'!K:K,0)),"")))
```

But I have little clue on how to convert it into VBA code. In the formula, the value i want lies in different worksheets in another workbook and I use IFERROR and INDEX MATCH to get the values I want.

Comment: Does iit work if you only do `range("H2").formula = ...`? in that case do that and use the fill down function insetad. I'm not sure it works when you try to do like you did here.

Comment: To fill down you do: `range("H2:H" & LR).filldown`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I've tried doing `range("H2").formula =` and it gives me the same "application-defined or object-defined error" whilst highlighting the formula.
The whole code itself doesn't have a problem because I've used the exact same code with different formula on another macro and it works

Comment: Can you manually insert that same formula in the cell?

Comment: Yes I can. That is why i think the issue lies with just the formula.

Comment: When you manually insert the formula in the cell, does it work? I'm presuming it doesn't. Can you provide the error message you get when you manually insert the formula in the cell

Comment: It works when manually inserting into cell. just not into VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the fix is simple use """" at the last iferrro instead of ""
`"=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]EXP'!N:N, MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]EXP'!L:L,0)), IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]AOG'!N:N,MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]AOG'!L:L,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]SCHED'!M:M,MATCH(G:G,'C:\Users\wwxuan\Desktop\KPI OUTBOUND 23.08.16\[KPI  Outbound - ( Aug ) Rev5.xlsx]SCHED'!K:K,0)),"""")))"`

Comment: Oh. My. God. Could have sworn I tried that. The solution is so simple it made me feel stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Do you also know if there is any way to wrap the formula so that it fits in the Visual Basic window? I tried `_` but just couldn't use it in the middle of the formula

Comment: @Andrew I think you need to escape the formula with `" &_"` but it was a long time ago since I wrapped code like that. I usually just leave it the way it is.